# Touchpad jumps randomly

Tags: touchpad, 17.10, libinput

Cursor is *somewhere*; remove finger from touchpad; put finger on touchpad again and cursor immediately jumps *somewhere else* entirely before continuing normally. It's making it very hard to use as I can't see where the pointer is until I wiggle round in circles to find it again! It's not every time but it's a lot of the time.

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL06E4:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Running 17.10. Laptop is Dell XPS15 9550.

I'm pretty sure that **libinput** is to blame - I didn't have these problems before upgrading to 17.10.

Any fixes? advice?